# Room Library database won't save data

Tags: android, android-room

So I have implemented Room Library database into my project in Android Studio. 
The issue is that everytime I close the app, the data is lost.

I have made an empty Migration:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
@Override
public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
}
};
```

As shown in [Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929)

I have tried to change the version number of the database multiple times, still didnt work.

Just to clarify how I create my database, firstly I prepopulate a single entity from assets, and after I have another entity which is populated according to users input.

EDIT:
This is how I init:

```
 @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null
    private const val NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4
    val databaseWriteExecutor: ExecutorService =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS)

    val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

        }
    }

    fun getDatabase(application: Application): MyDatabase? {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(MyDatabase::class.java) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        application.applicationContext,
                        MyDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
                    )
                        .createFromAsset(DATABASE_DIR)
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .build()
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE
```

Comment: Can you share a room initialization code? You might init Room to be saved in memory instead of in internal storage

Comment: It's done! Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something wrong with pre-populating your DB.
Seems app pre-populating your DB from scratch every time time it's initialized.
Please try to comment this line and launch app again to see your saved data exists in DB.

Also would be good to read https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/packing-the-room-pre-populate-your-database-with-this-one-method-333ae190e680

Comment: So you mean I should re-install the app? Cuz if i do that, the database will be empty anw

Comment: just comment .createFromAsset(DATABASE_DIR) and launch app again to see if data saved from your previous session is not removed. No fresh installation